# Convert moves in PGN notation (SAN) to long algebraic

Tags: php, chess

I'd like to grab a list of moves from a PGN file (written in Standard Algebraic Notation or SAN) and convert it to Long Algebraic Notation. I considered the use of a PHP chess engine, but I can't find one that is small and just enough for what I want to do (most are packed with online playing, databases, e-mail messaging and so on).

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You cant check the javascript librarys http://chessboardjs.com/ for drawing the board in your html website and https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js for control the chess movements on the board.